# Access Input Form with Custom Error Messages

Tags: ms-access, vba

**The Solution**

The solution was to not try and capture the errors but do the error handling myself as part of the Add New Record command button:

```
Private Sub buttonNewRecord_Click()

Dim ErrorInt As Integer
Dim TeleCheck As Variant

Name.SetFocus
If Name.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "Name is missing!"
ErrorInt = ErrorInt + 1
End If

TeleCheck = DLookup("[Telephone]", "tblColdCallLog", "[Telephone] = '" & Me.Telephone & "'")
If Not IsNull(TeleCheck) Then
MsgBox "Telephone number already exists in the table!"
ErrorInt = ErrorInt + 1
End If

If ErrorInt < 1 Then
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
MsgBox "Record Added!"
End If

End Sub
```

Original Post:

**What I Have:**

I have created a simple Access 2013 Form used to input data into a table. On the Form, the user enters data into the fields and clicks on a button made using the Command Button Wizard to Add New Record.

The form has one required field, [Name], and one field set to 'Index: Yes (No Duplicates)', [Telephone Number]. In the Form, this correctly produces error messages if the [Name] field is empty or there is a duplicate number detected in the [Telephone] field that is also in the table.

**What I Am Trying To Do:**

The error messages that appear are not user friendly. I would like to replace them with custom error messages and if there are no errors, maybe a message that says all went well.

**What I Have Tried:**

On the Form properties, Events tab, in 'On Error', [Event Procedure]:

```
Private Sub Error_Sub(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
  If DataErr = 3022 Then
    MsgBox "Duplicate telephone number found in table!"
    Response = acDataErrContinue
  End If
  If DataErr = 3314 Then
    MsgBox "Name is missing!"
    Response = acDataErrContinue
  End If
End Sub
```

This works but only when you close the Form... When you click the 'Add New Record' Command Button, it simply shows the default error messages when appropriate.

Maybe I should use the Event 'Before Update'? I can't seem to use the same VBA script. I'm not allowed to define DataErr or Response. So, I'll use an Expression instead:

```
=IIf(Error(3022),MsgBox("Duplicate telephone number found in table"))
=IIf(Error(3314),MsgBox("Name is missing"))
```

This works... but when there is no error. Even if there is a name in the [Name] field, the error shows but at least it replaces the default error message.

Let's put it in the button itself? I'll have to use the Macro Builder to edit it. It's a bit hard to copy and paste this one so I'll simplify:

```
OnError GoTo Error_Handling
GoToRecord New
If [MacroError]<>0 Then 
   MsgBox = "[MacroError].[Description]"
End If

Error_Handling:
If Error(3022) Then
  MsgBox = "Duplicate telephone number found in table!"
End If
If Error(3314) Then
  MsgBox = "Name is missing!"
End If
```

This does the same as the 'Before Update' event; replaces the default error message but regardless of whether or not the error message should be triggered in the first place.

What am I doing wrong? I get the feeling it's something really simple. I've tried a variety of other combinations and endless Googling but I feel stumped.

Comment: When adding records I nearly always use an unbound form and check each required control (field) before running an update query with parameters. This is scalable.

Comment: The best option is to _prevent_ input errors. Do that in the BeforeUpdate event of the form or - if possible - in the Before- or AfterUpdate event of the individual controls. Then let the form's error handling take care of other errors, typically those out of the user's control.

Comment: Thanks both. Gustav put me on the right track. Instead of trying to capture the errors, I wrote the error handling myself as part of the Add New Record button. Solution added to OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub buttonNewRecord_Click()

Dim ErrorInt As Integer
Dim TeleCheck As Variant

Name.SetFocus
If Name.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "Name is missing!"
ErrorInt = ErrorInt + 1
End If

TeleCheck = DLookup("[Telephone]", "tblColdCallLog", "[Telephone] = '" & Me.Telephone & "'")
If Not IsNull(TeleCheck) Then
MsgBox "Telephone number already exists in the table!"
ErrorInt = ErrorInt + 1
End If

If ErrorInt < 1 Then
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
MsgBox "Record Added!"
End If

End Sub
```