# Access VBA - Input Form Detect Duplicate and then Display Duplicate Record

Tags: vba, ms-access

**What I Have**:

I have an Access input form, the user fills in data in the form, pushes a button which triggers a VBA script which checks if the input telephone number in the [Telephone] control matches an entry in the table. If there's a duplicate it triggers a MsgBox, if not it commits the data to the table. This works and it's great. Here is the script:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub buttonNewRecord_Click()

Dim ErrorInt As Integer
Dim TeleCheck As Variant

TeleCheck = DLookup("[Telephone]", "tblLog", "[Telephone] = '" & Me.Telephone & "'")
If Not IsNull(TeleCheck) Then
MsgBox "Telephone number already exists in the database!"
ErrorInt = ErrorInt + 1
End If

If ErrorInt < 1 Then
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
MsgBox "Record Added!"
End If

End Sub
```

**What I Am Trying To Do**:

In the table, along with [Telephone], there is a [Date] and [Customer_Name] field. When a duplicate telephone number is  detected, I would like the triggered MsgBox to display the [Date] and [Customer_Name] of the record where the duplicate was found. Like:

```
MsgBox "Telephone number already exists for [Customer_Name] added on [Date]!"
```

**What I Have Tried**:

Not a lot because I'm not sure what to try. Googling provides a lot of different ways to detect a duplicate but I have found no one trying to return any data from the record of the duplicate found.

Comment: Why not add a unique constraint for that field in the table? That'll prevent duplicates without having to check for it explicitly. You can catch the error when a duplicate is attempted to be added, and just display a message box.

Comment: Because I found capturing the error to be far more trouble than it was worth. I also have additional error handling and constraints in the VBA that I have no listed here because they are not relevant to the issue.

Comment: How so? It should throw a pretty specific error number.

Comment: Sorry but this is really not relevant to the issue... I have no problem detecting the error, the issue is including additional information about the duplicate record in the error message. If you really want to know, you can read the thread I made about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220010/access-input-form-with-custom-error-messages

Comment: Use a recordset to return the fields you are interested in when the telephone number already exists

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim cstmerName as String
Dim dateAdded as String

Let cstmerName = DLookup("[Customer_Name]", "tblLog", "[Telephone] = '" & Me.Telephone & "'")
Let dateAdded = CStr(DLookup("[Date]", "tblLog", "[Telephone] = '" & Me.Telephone & "'"))

MsgBox "Telephone number already exists for " & cstmerName & " added on " & dateAdded & "!"
```